# Date picker stuck at 1970

Tags: civimember, dates

We recently updated CiviCRM to 5.13.5 and have noticed that the date picker for memberships and relationships have stopped working. It is working for events and  other areas. Can anyone help please.  [image]

Comment: I saved the date format numerous times and had to change the format to dd-mm-yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy which is not the best solution but that fixed it after multiple saves. I also updated localisation settings and resaved again.

Comment: I'm not seeing this on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. After upgrade did you try cleaning cache and deleting the templates_c folder?

Comment: Do you have any js errors?

Comment: Thanks @SohalKhatwani I had a similar problem - the date field for end date had no datepicker and wouldn't allow the usual format (dd/mm/yyyy) but when I replaced it with dd-mm-yyyy once and saved, then it's fixed across the whole site.